# If $d_1\sim d_2$ and $I:(E,d_1)\to(E,d_2) $, prove that $I$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

**Edit:** If $d_1\sim d_2$ and $$I:(E,d_1)\to(E,d_2) $$
$$x\mapsto I(x)=x. $$ I want to prove that $I$ is continuous.

Here is my trial: Since $d_1\sim d_2$, then $\exists \alpha, \beta>0$ such that $\alpha d_2\leq d_1 \leq\beta d_2$.

Let $\{x_n\}\subset E$ be Cauchy $\implies x_n\to x.$ So, $\forall \epsilon>0,\; \exists\;n_0$ such that $\forall\;n\geq n_0,$ $$d_1(x_n,x)<\epsilon.$$

So, $$\alpha d_2(I(x_n),I(x))= \alpha d_2(x_n,x)\leq d_1(x_n,x)< \epsilon,$$
which implies
$$ d_2(I(x_n),I(x))< \frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}=\epsilon'.$$

Also,

$$d_1(x_n,x)\leq \beta d_2(x_n,x)= \beta d_2(I(x_n),I(x))< \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\epsilon\leq\epsilon.$$

Please, is this right? If no, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You are right. The identity map in the other direction is also continuous, from a similar argument.

Comment: @Mike Your definition of equivalent metrics is not the standard one.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: I have a question! $\beta$ doesn't have to be less than $\alpha,$ right?

Comment: $\alpha d_2<\beta d_2$ for $\beta<\alpha$ is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Fakemistake: I have edited my post but what is the actual relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: (1). If $\beta =\alpha$ then $d_2=d_1,$ which is a (trivial) special case. But it does not need special treatment in the proof.  (2).  If such $\alpha, \beta $ exist then $d_1,d_2$ are called uniformly equivalent. Metrics which generate the same topology are called equivalent.  On $\Bbb R$ the metrics $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$  and $d_2(x,y)=\min (1,|x-y|)$ are equivalent but not uniformly equivalent.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Thanks for your answer! So, what do you think about the proof? Is it correct now? If no, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Replace the 2nd sentence "Let $\{x_n\}$ be Cauchy .." which seems to say that a $d_1$-Cauchy sequence must have a limit. Say "Let $\lim_{n\to \infty} d(x,x_n)=0.$ Or say "Let $\{x_n\}$ be $d_1$-convergent to $x.$"... It is true that uniformly equivalent metrics do have the same Cauchy sequences,  but to prove topological equivalence  it is sufficient to prove that $d_1$ and $d_2$ have the same convergent sequences.

Comment: What is  $f$? You had  $I=id_X.$...  In an $(\epsilon,n)$ or $(\epsilon,\delta)$ type of proof it is customary to "reverse-engineer" it so that you get a last line like " For any $\epsilon>0$ there are only finitely many $n$ such that $d_2(I(x_n),I(x))\geq \epsilon$ " by stating earlier that for any $\epsilon >0$ there are only finitely many $n$ such that $d_1(x_n,x)\geq \alpha \epsilon.$ YOUR PROOF IS OK in that you have exactly the right understanding.  Perhaps there should be ( compulsory?) courses on math-writing, instead of expecting everyone to become skilled at it on their own.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Thanks a lot for your comment! You are indeed, right! However, I'll still edit the proof!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You <strike>are</strike> were only missing to say that $d_1(x_n,x)<\epsilon$, **for $n>n_0$**.

A small detail that may not need to be mentioned but that needs to at least be kept in mind is that we are proving continuity of a function using sequences, because the topology comes from a metric. Depending on the definition of "continuous" used this can either be the definition of continuous or a theorem.

For other topologies checking the limits along sequences is not enough. However, for topologies arising from a metric, it is.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!